# How to only show a certain amount of labels in iOS-Charts Framework

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I made a line graph using iOS Charts and for my xAxis all of my labels are dates, but because there are so many they overlap. What could I do to stop this? Is there also a way I could scale in on a certain part of the graph to do this?

Comment: Are you using :https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts ?

Comment: Yeah, that’s the one I’m using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try limiting the labelCount

```
var lineChart = LineChartView()

// Fix them to what ever number suitable 
lineChart.xAxis.labelCount = 3
```